# Unable to execute 2 MySQL queries separated by semicolon

Tags: php, mysql, sql-injection

I am trying a simple SQL Injection example which is already working correctly. The goal is to add SQL code to a login page that asks for EmployeeID and Password. In this example I am supposed to know the following information:
* There is a user called Admin
* There is a table field called Name

With this data at hand, the code below did the trick. A space is included after the second dash in order to be interpreted as a comment so the rest of the query is ignored. Basically, the password information is not necessary.

```
' or Name = 'Admin'; --
```

So far, so good. Now, I have to include a second SQL statement and I am told that I can use a semicolon as a separator for multiple SQL statements. So I did the following:

```
' or Name = 'Admin'; SELECT id FROM credential; --
```

But it does not work. I get a message saying that there is an error in the SQL syntax. I thought that maybe there is no support for multiple queries in one line but I tested using MySQL console and I could successfully issue 2 select statements separated by a semicolon. Below, I show the query (displayed intentionally by an echo statement) and the error that appears on screen.

I will very much appreciate your feedback to help me discover and fix my issue.

```
SELECT id, name, eid, salary, birth, ssn, phoneNumber, address, email,nickname,Password FROM credential WHERE eid= '' or Name = 'Admin'; SELECT id FROM credential; -- ' and Password='da39a3ee5e6b4b0d3255bfef95601890afd80709'


There was an error running the query [You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT id FROM credential; -- ' and Password='da39a3ee5e6b4b0d3255bfef95601890af' at line 3]\n
```

Comment: The final `and password` section of your query is not in any query and has no context. what are you trying to do? you cant have conditions without `SELECT` and `FROM` first. That is what is causing your syntax error. if your trying to comment that part use `#` not `--`

Comment: sure mysql console and phpmyadmin support the colon, but it will depend on how you are excecuting this in your code.

Comment: The final " and password " is part of the original query that belongs to the web page. That is why I need to use comments in order to ignore it. Can you please explain what you mean by "you cant have conditions without SELECT and FROM first.". The following query worked in MySQL console:     mysql> SELECT * FROM credential WHERE Name = 'Admin'; SELECT * FROM credential; (I am sorry, I could not highlight code)